# Elementary probability theory

Tags: probability-theory

I would like to ask a simple question but I'm unable to understand the logic behind it.

> From an urn containing $M$ balls $n$ balls are drawn with replacement. What is the probability that at least one ball is drawn more than once?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I checked the possible duplicate question but seems like the other one is without replacement.

Comment: There're two sections: *with replacement* and *without replacement*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In questions such as this, it is useful to think of the complement of these events. What is the complement of at least one ball being drawn more than once; each ball drawn is distinct. So even though you are replacing the balls, the number of 'good' choices starts decreasing. So the first time, you have $M$ choices, the next time $M-1$, and so on. Meanwhile, the total number of possible choices is $M^n$. Does that seem fine?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I understood the logic with your help but the answer is supposed to be P(A) = 1- M*(M-1)....(M-n+1)/M^n as you said. However, I didn't quite get where this (M-n+1) comes from. I'm unable to visualize the answer.

Comment: How many times do you pick the balls? $n$ times. So how many valid options do you have on the last turn?

Comment: Thank you very much that was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The complement is ‘each ball is distinct’. Its cardinal is equal to the number of injections  from a set with $n$ elements to a set with $M$ elements.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I got it!